# Cannot find media_id field in new oEmbed Instagram API

Tags: python, api, instagram, oembed

I have a piece of code that was using this API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed-legacy. But it is now deprecated. As you can see it returns media_id in response but the new API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed/ that is made as a replacement to this API does not have media_id field in the response. Can someone help me in finding media_id